# Choosing php version in multilanguage travis project

Tags: php, composer-php, travis-ci

I have a multi-language project (php and python at the moment). Currently i just run Python test suite using Travis and i would like to add the PHP test suite.

Multiple languages cannot be added in the `language` tag, so, as [explained here](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/538) you should install what you need for any additional languages. Indeed php and composer are already present in the default image. But it is PHP5 and not PHP7 which i need. PHP7 is not available as apt packages in Ubuntu/Trusty either. Can anyone figure out how to setup that?

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: This solution is not a documented solution neither Travis way. I figured it out myself by injecting commands to inspect the image content. So, not sure this is the proper way to go. So, confirmation or a better answer is still welcome)

Travis is currently using [phpenv](https://github.com/phpenv/phpenv), not `apt`, in order to have multiple versions of php. The default image currently contains 5.6, 7.0 and 7.1 versions. I tried to define `PHPENV_VERSION` environment in the `env` section but it does not work. You get the proper environment by calling the proper `phpenv local` subcommand.

```
language: python
python:
- "2.7"
- "3.5"
- "3.6"
env: # This should have effect by itself but it doesn't
- PHPENV_VERSION="7.0"
- PHPENV_VERSION="7.1"
before_install:
- php --version # This will still show 5.6
- phpenv local $PHPENV_VERSION # This is required
- php --version # Here you got the one
```

A complete solution would be installing any listed version that is not on the image. It could be done with the documented `phpenv install` subcommand but it is not available in the phpenv version of the image.